# Modifiying Jquery to reset as browser window is to be re-size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a responsive layout with similar divs and I am applying Jquery as so all divs match the height of the one with more content. However, if the browser window is to be re-size all divs remain the same heigh as when the page was loaded making the text go out of the div. Is there a way to somehow continue running the Jquery everytime the user resize the browser window?

To be more descriptive as of what I'm trying to acomplish it is to have my divs behave (on browser window rezise)as a normal div with text content and attributes width: #%; height: auto; with the only difference that all divs will match the height of the one with the bigger height.

Here is the link of what I have: http://as.sjsu.edu/cf/vaishak/equalizeTest/index.html

Here is the Jquery that I originally have to get max height:

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
var maxHeight = 0;
$(".box").each(function(){
   if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
});
$(".box").height(maxHeight);
});
</script>
```

Here is the updated version that still doesn't work properly when window is resize.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(event) {
        resizeDiv();
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        resizeDiv();
    });
    function resizeDiv(){
        var maxHeight = 0;
        $(".box").each(function(){
           if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
        });
        $(".box").height(maxHeight);
    }
    });
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using JavaScript to make the elements equal heights rather than pure CSS?

Comment: I don't know of any way of how to do this with pure css and my layout is responsive so I can't fake it with a bg img under the divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just forget about using JavaScript for this and use pure CSS:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/ygq5x6k3

```
<div class="container">
    <div>First</div>
    <div>Second</div>
</div>

.container {
    display: table; /* optional */
    width: 100%; /* optional */
}

.container div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Its flexible and works with as many "columns" as you need.  Since its pure CSS, you can even disable it for mobile devices via media queries.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. This seems to work, but is there a way to have margins between divs. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish: http://as.sjsu.edu/cf/vaishak/equalizeTest/index.html

Comment: Sure:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/ogu17bqd.  You'll need to use negative margins to offset them along the outer edge.

Comment: I fake the margin with a border of the same color of the background.

Comment: Oh Thanks, One more thing, is there a way to stack this divs vertically when viewed in smaller screens?

Comment: I didn't realize you had already suggested. I was able to apply media queries and make it work as I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, you can use JQuery's `.resize()` event documented here: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

For example:

`$(window).resize(function() { // YOUR CODE HERE });`

Then every time the window resizes, the code will run.

Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wUGfH/) that demonstrates when the code runs.

Answer (score 1):

This is what event listeners are for. You can put your code into a function, say `normalizeBoxHeight()` and then call it when the browser resizes (and initially on load).

Looks like this:

```
jQuery(function(){

    var normalizeBoxHeight = function(){
        var maxHeight = 0;
        $(".box").each(function(){
           if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
        });
        $(".box").height(maxHeight);
    }

    $(window).resize(normalizeBoxHeight);
    normalizeBoxHeight();

});
```

Comment: Actually, I still don't get what I'm trying to accomplish and text goes off after I resize window. :/

Comment: well I will tell you that this code does what you've asked for (fires initially and after a window resize). If it's not producing the desired effect, it has to do with your markup/CSS or other js. Feel free to provide some of that to see if we can't troubleshoot further.

Comment: You may be rigth and ther is something else. Here is the link: http://as.sjsu.edu/cf/vaishak/equalizeTest/index.html Thanks for helping me.